# importing image in tkinter as Button

Tags: python, tkinter

Today I tried to put an image in a tkinter file and I tried `PhotoImage`. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file = './Images/Test.png')
Button(screen, text = 'Click Me !', image = photo).pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

When I run it in VSCode:

```
File "/Users/pyman/Desktop/Coding/python/Periodic
table/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    photo = PhotoImage(file = './Images/Test.png')   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
line 3377, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
line 3331, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "./Images/Test.png"
```

When I run it in IDLE,
I don't get any error.

What I should do to run it in VS Code?

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is, since current working directory is not the same when you run the code int VSCode, so it's not the same .png file.